# Closed form formula for lower bound on induced max norm of inverse matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am working with the induced max-norm of the inverse of an $n \times n$ matrix $V$ (it is a variance-covariance matrix).

Let $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ be the max vector norm.

I know:

$|| V^{-1} || = \max_{||x||=1} || V^{-1} x||_{\infty} = \left[\min_{||x||=1} ||Vx||_{\infty}\right]^{-1}$.

I'm looking for a characterization of:

$\min_{||x||=1} ||Vx||_{\infty}$.

I know the induced max-norm (replacing "min" with "max" above) is the maximum absolute row sum.  Is there a similar characterization for the minimum?  Do we know this minimum as a closed-form formula of the elements of the matrix?

If there is no exact characterization, is there a lower bound on the minimum that is a closed form formula of the elements of $V$?